# Property '<properyName>' of exported interface has or is using private name '<name>'

Tags: typescript, interface, encapsulation

I declare an `interface`:

```
export interface ApiClientMetodOptions {
    initialFilterSatement?: string;
    fieldsMapping?: {
        [K in keyof P]?: string;
    };
    requestParams?: IRequestParams<P>;
    additionalParams?: {
        [key: string]: unknown;
    };
    additionalHeaders?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    cancelOption?: IRequestCancelOption;
}
```

but get following error: 
`Property 'fieldsMapping' of exported interface has or is using private name 'P'.`
I done this for encapsulate the type and using it in some methods. For example:

```
export interface IApiClient {
    /**
     * Generic function for fetching a list of a certain instances
     * @param fieldsMapping function converting fields of `P`-type object to a query field names
*/
getEntities<P, T>(
    url: string,
    options: {
        instanceToEntity?: (instance: unknown) => T;
    } & ApiClientMetodOptions,
): Promise<T[]>;
```

I don't know `"typescript"` very deeply. What I'm doing wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Where `P` comes from? If it is generic type parameter, you should declare it, e.g. `interface ApiClientMetodOptions<P>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the generic parameter `P` to your interface definition like this:

```
export interface ApiClientMetodOptions<P> {
    initialFilterSatement?: string;
    fieldsMapping?: {
        [K in keyof P]?: string;
    };
    requestParams?: IRequestParams<P>;
    additionalParams?: {
        [key: string]: unknown;
    };
    additionalHeaders?: {
        [key: string]: string;
    };
    cancelOption?: IRequestCancelOption;
}
```

And then in your method defintion add the parameter as well:

```
export interface IApiClient {
    /**
     * Generic function for fetching a list of a certain instances
     * @param fieldsMapping function converting fields of `P`-type object to a query field names
*/
getEntities<P, T>(
    url: string,
    options: {
        instanceToEntity?: (instance: unknown) => T;
    } & ApiClientMetodOptions<P>,
): Promise<T[]>;
```